# Liferay : How can I land to custom url on signout

Tags: liferay, logout

I'm not sure if I can achieve this by simply configuration or I need to override LogoutAction for it.

I've configured multiple organisation and each organisation has there own site which I want to navigate to my custom url for different site instead of default url on logout from liferay.

[EDITED]
I want to navigate on different url for each site, not a common url.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use `default.logout.page.path` property (in portal-ext.properties file)

```
default.logout.page.path=
#default.logout.page.path=/web/guest/logout
```

Comment: Yeah appreciated. But I missed a bit in my requirement...  this is the option but this always land me to same url for different site. What in case I want to land to a different url for different site. I've edited my original question for this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this by overriding `LogoutPostAction` through a hook.

1. Define your `LogoutPostAction` class in `portal.properties` of your hook:

   ```
   logout.events.post=com.my.action.MyLogoutPostAction
   ```
2. Here is a sample code for the class to redirect to your desired page:

   ```
   public class MyLogoutPostAction extends Action {

       @Override
       public void run(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
           throws ActionException {

           try {
               doRun(request, response);
           }
           catch (Exception e) {
               throw new ActionException(e);
           }
       }

       protected void doRun(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
           throws Exception {

           long groupId = PortalUtil.getScopeGroupId(httpReq);

           // code to fetch the Group
           // ....
           // ....

           // 
           String postLogoutURL = "create your own URL";

           // if required: add a parameter
           postLogoutURL = HttpUtil.setParameter(postLogoutURL, "my_param", "my_param_value");

           // redirect to that URL
           response.sendRedirect(postLogoutURL);
       }

   }
   ```

The only thing that can be a road block with this approach would be if Liferay has lost context of the current group from which the user was logged-out. I have not tested the code.

Comment: Liferay does lose context of the current group. It displays as "Guest". What would you do in this scenario?